# iOS BLE read value characteristics issue "The attribute is not long" error

Tags: objective-c

I am working in BLE communication, write value to peripheral is working Fine.

When i read data from BLE device using `readValueCharacteristics` shows

> error code 11 The attribute is not long

in `didUpdateValueForCharacteristics` method while reading data from Characteristics "FFF2" (Read and Write).

Anybody Guide me on this issue it will be great.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280429/reading-long-characteristic-values-using-corebluetooth ?

Comment: Can you please add code snippets to your question?